# My Python code isn't pulling all the information from the .csv excel file and I cannot figure out why

Tags: python, excel, csv, graph, plot

I'm pretty new to the coding scene and my boss has kinda just thrown me into the fire, so I'm sorry if this is some rookie mistake, though I don't think it is.

So I'm trying to graph G versus l1 (that's not an eleven, but an L1).  The data is in the file that I loaded from an excel file.  The excel file is 14x250 so there are 14 arguments, each with 250 data points.  The graph I put up is formatted correctly, but zero y-values show up.  From what I can tell, the code is graphing the first 12 columns and leaving the last 2 columns (which contain the two sets of 'y' data) out.  I cannot find where the error is and it's driving me crazy! ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

## This is where I formatted the excel file and where I believe the mistake is:

```
header = ['l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'l4', 'l5', 'EI',
      'S', 'P_right', 'P1_0', 'P3_0',
      'w_left', 'w_right', 'G_left', 'G_right']

def loadfile(filename, skip=[], *args):
    output = []
    with open(filename, *args) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            if not(i in skip):
                output.append(row)
    return np.array(output)
```

## This is where I actually loaded the excel file, which  is the next likely place there is a mistake:

```
outputs_l1 = [loadfile('FILE.csv'.format(p)) for p in p3_arr]

fig = plt.figure()
for output, col in zip(outputs_l1, colors):
    plt.plot(output[:,0], output[:,10]*1E3, col+'-')
plt.legend(['$P3 = {} Pa$'.format(p) for p in p3_arr], loc=(1.05, 0.6), fontsize=16)
for output, col in zip(outputs_l1, colors):
    plt.plot(output[:,0], output[:,11]*1E3, col+'--')
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='both', style='plain', scilimits=(-1,1))
plt.xlabel('$l1 (m)$')
plt.ylabel('G $(J / m^2) * 10^{-3}$')
plt.xlim(xmin=.2)
plt.ylim(ymax=2, ymin=0)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8, bottom=0.15, right=0.7)
```

Comment: What is the expected output of `'FILE.csv'.format(p)`?

Comment: It is an excel file containing, for this program, 10 columns (each with 250 rows) of constants and 4 columns ("") with varying data.  I am to graph this data (G vs. L1) and plot it.  My plot works fine, except that it is unable to read the last two columns which contain all the y-values for the plot

Comment: That's not what I was asking. I wanted to know what you expect that bit of code to do. The reason being is `'FILE.csv'.format(p)` will return `'FILE.csv'`. My original suspicion was that you were loading the wrong file (several times due to your list comprehension) unintentionally. It appears you've solved your problem, so it doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using column names instead of numbers and combining the two plotting loops,

```
col = {name:i for i,name in enumerate(header)}

fig = plt.figure()
for data,color in zip(outputs_l1, colors):
    xs  = data[:, col["l1"     ]]
    wl = data[:, col["w_left" ]] * 1000.0    # column 10
    wr = data[:, col["w_right"]] * 1000.0    # column 11
    plt.plot(xs, wl, color + "-", wr, color + "--")
```

a possible error becomes clear: you say you want to graph `G`, but you are specifying `w` instead (cols 10 and 11, instead of cols 12 and 13).

Maybe `w_left` and `w_data` do not appear because they are outside your specified limits (`plt.ylim(ymax=2, ymin=0)`)?

I think what you actually want is

```
fig = plt.figure()
for data,color in zip(outputs_l1, colors):
    xs  = data[:, col["l1"     ]]
    gl = data[:, col["G_left" ]] * 1000.0    # column 12
    gr = data[:, col["G_right"]] * 1000.0    # column 13
    plt.plot(xs, gl, color + "-", gr, color + "--")
```

---

In

```
def loadfile(filename, skip=[], *args):
```

passing `[]` as a default argument is a bit dangerous because changes to the default list can persist across calls to the function, causing very strange results. You should instead do

```
def loadfile(filename, skip=None, *args):
    skip = skip or []
```

except you are only using skip for membership-testing, so it would be faster as a set, so it becomes

```
def loadfile(filename, skip=None, *args):
    skip = set(skip or [])
```

---

Also,

```
    output = []
    with open(filename, *args) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            if not(i in skip):
                output.append(row)
    return np.array(output)
```

could be shortened to

```
    with open(filename, *args) as f:
        cr = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        return np.array(row for i,row in enumerate(cr) if i not in skip)
```

and the result is a numpy 2d array; so

```
outputs_l1 = [loadfile('FILE.csv'.format(p)) for p in p3_arr]
```

looks like `p3_arr` is a list determining which data-sets you want to look at; then `outputs_l1` becomes a list of 2d arrays. This is a misleading name because, looking at `header`, `l1` is supposed to be the first column of each 2d array; thus `outputs_l1` logically ought to be a 2d array containing just first-column data. I suggest renaming it to something like `p_data`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You're a life saver!  When using your first suggestion, I recieve the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILE", line 119, in <module>
    gl = data[:, col["G_left" ]] * 1000.0    # column 12
IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 12"

Comment: Also, after following all of your suggestions, I get the error message "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILE.py", line 115, in <module>
    xs  = data[:, col["l1"     ]]
IndexError: too many indices for array"